# How to push a bug upstream on github

Tags: github

I've forked a repo on github to do my own customistations.

However, along the way, I discovered a bug and fixed it and would like to send a pull request upstream.

I followed the guide at:
http://gun.io/blog/how-to-github-fork-branch-and-pull-request/

And have created a branch with just the bugfix on it - but when I go to submit a pull request to the upstream - it lists all the changes I've made since I forked, I can't seem to find a way to isolate the bug fix patch.
I don't want to send all my changes, and I'm guessing they don't want to receive them - so how do I send just the bug fix?

If it helps, the repo is
https://github.com/chrisjensen/ankusa
The branch is untrainfix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way pull requests work is to apply a commit from a fork on top of the upstream repo.

For that, the easiest way is to make your fix on *the same branch* than the one you intend to apply it (by making a pull request) on the upstream repo.

In other words, all your changes should be done in a custom branch, except for the fix, that you should do (or report by cherry-picking) on the same branch than the one used in the original upstream repo.

If you want to fix a bug on `master` from upstream, make your fix in the `master` branch of your fork, by first making sure your `master` branch is identical (`git pull`) to the one in upstream.

Comment: Ok. So since I've already made my customisations on the master branch of my fork i can either:
- Revert those changes on the master branch (not very appealing), or
- Create an entirely new fork, and apply just the fix to the master branch

and the submit a pull request from the master branch?

Comment: @ChristopherJ no, you make a branch on top of master, then reset master to upstream/master. No need to revert anything or recreate a repo.